# dsmod user title - Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format

Tags: active-directory, dsquery

I want to edit a large number of users' title field on Active Directory that I have listed in a CSV file.

I can get every attribute associated with a user if I run this:

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=%UsrFld%))" -attr * -limit 0
```

However, if I attempt to do the following to edit the "title" field, using this:

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=%promptusername%))" -attr * -limit 0| dsmod user -title Disabled User
```

I get the following error:

```
dsmod failed:Value for 'Target object for this command' has incorrect format.
```

Now obviously DSMOD is telling me that that it can't interpret the first half of my syntax as an object to edit. My question is, how do I edit the title field with the query I'm using?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the output from the dsquery is all of the attributes of the user object and dsmod is just expecting the userDN.  Unfortunately I ran into this trying to use dsquery * with the mail field, I had dsquery just output the attr of distinguishedName but the output is without quotes.

My dsquery:
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectcategory=person)(objectclass=user)(mail=somedude@contoso.com))" -attr distinguishedName -L

The output is:
CN=Some Dude,OU=BitInspector,OU=Bit Makers,OU=Mfgs,DC=Contoso,DC=Com

Dsmod is expecting input with quotes like this:
"CN=Some Dude,OU=BitInspector,OU=Bit Makers,OU=Mfgs,DC=Contoso,DC=Com" because the userDN has spaces in it, thus the need for quotes.

Unfortunately I never could figure out how to put quotes around the dsquery output so I ended up going to PowerShell.